# bluebird: access value returned from last then callback

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Is there some way to retrieve whatever was returned from last `then` callback (or passed to initial `Promise.resolve()`/ `resolve()`)?

```
const p = Bluebird.resolve().then(() => {
    // I need to access this by inspecting `p` variable
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
});

// or
const p = Bluebird.resolve(
    // I need to access this by inspecting `p` variable
    new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
);

// or
const p = new Bluebird( resolve => {
    resolve(
        // I need to access this by inspecting `p` variable
        new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    )
});
```

By inspecting `p` variable, I mean I want to retrieve that last return value by doing something like:

```
const intermediate = new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
const p = Bluebird.resolve().then(() => {
    return intermediate;
});
console.log( p.SOME_PROPERTY_OR_METHOD === intermediate ); // => true
```

`p.SOME_PROPERTY_OR_METHOD` is sync call returning `intermediate` value without waiting for promise resolution.

Resolving with `new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));` as an arbitrary example to indicate that the `p` will be in `pending` state at the time of inspection. Thus, I can't use `.value()` (which I wouldn't want to use anyway, because I don't want resolution value).

The reason why isn't important but in case you're interested it's for purpose of deciding whether to cancel the promise or not (as part of one abstraction I'm working on).

Comment: Typically you would hold a reference to the previous promise and could `.then` (or `.value`) it.

Comment: Also, "I need to access this by inspecting `p` variable" - what exactly is "this"?

Comment: edited with further expl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple supported way to do this with Bluebird. The reason why is that no one ever asked us and we're very hesitant about adding features at this point.

The closest you can get is using the monitoring feature, you'd turn it on with:

```
Promise.config({ monitoring: true });
```

And then listen to creation events in either the browser or Node:

```
self.addEventListener("promiseChained", function(event) {
  // event.type - "promiseCreated"
  // event.details.promise - promise object that was chained to child promise
  // event.details.child - child promise object
});
```

See [the documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/features.html#promise-monitoring) for usage patterns.